# Refactoring predicate out of the Lambda expressoin caueses an exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'm having a method, that builds a large Lambda expression based on the incoming parameters (filter for db query, Entity Framework v. 1.0).
Let's say we've a Person, Department, and Occupation entities.
Person can have Occupations, and Occupation belongs to a Department.

Here is the code:

```
var query = myDbContext.AsQueryable();
query = query.Persons.Where(.......) //Building some conditions
...
... //Adding conditions to the query if there are incoming params
```

The problem lies in the following fragment:

```
//We have a Department Id as parameter, so we want to filter persons whose Occupations belong to this Department
query = query.Where(per => per.Occupations.Where(occ => !occ.IsDeleted).Count(occ => occ.Department.Id == myFilterParameter) > 0;)
```

This works fine, but when refactoring the predicate for Count() costruction out from the expresion, like so:

```
Expression<Func<Occupation, bool>> countExpression = occ => occ.DepartmentId == myFilterParameter;
query = query.Where(per => per.Occupations.Where(occ => !occ.IsDeleted).Count(countExpression.Compile()) > 0);
```

It causes

Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.

Any ideas why it is happening so?

I tried also:

```
query = query.Where(per => per.Occupations.Where(occ => !occ.IsDeleted).AsQueryable().Count(countExpression.Compile()) > 0), the same picture.
```

Any help would be very appreciable.

Comment: Instead of `Count(occ => occ.Department.Id == myFilterParameter) > 0` use `Any(occ => occ.Department.Id == myFilterParameter)`

Comment: Tried `(occ => !occ.IsDeleted).Any(countExpression.Compile())`, the same exception :(

Answer (score 1):

Typo:

`Expression<Func<Occupation, bool>> countExpression = occ => occ.DepartmentId = myFilterParameter;`

this should be:

`Expression<Func<Occupation, bool>> countExpression = occ => occ.DepartmentId == myFilterParameter;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Compile()` on `countExpression.Compile()`

Edit - Have you tried something like this?

```
query.Where(per => per.Occupations
                      .Where(occ => !occ.IsDeleted)
                      .Any(countExpression));
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped to avoid error 1025. But a new error has occured. `Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.` When debugging it cleared, that this exception occurs later in the code, when `query.Count()` is being called.

Comment: Tried also: `query.Where(per => per.Occupations.Where(occ => !occ.IsDeleted).AsQueryable().Any(countExpression));`, the same result